# why the wp_register_script doesn't work for register_activation_hook

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script

I want to register a script when my plugin is activated. So I wrote:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'register_script');
function register_script(){
   wp_register_script('addjs','http://example.com/exmple.js');
}
```

Next, I created a meta box and enqueued the script in the `add_meta_boxes` hook:

```
wp_enqueue_script('addjs');
```

But that doesn't work. Why? My js file is just a simple alert function. However, when I register my script using init hook or other hook, my code works - why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever is hooked to activation runs in just a single request when the plugin is activated in a sandbox, and the output is captured to check for errors. Your code won't run on any subsequent request after that single activation, so your script will not be registered. It works on init because that action runs on every request.

Comment: err, I actually quite confuse, actually i just want to register my script once when my plugin activated right?>

Comment: you have to register it on every request you want it present on. code hooked to an action doesn't persist beyond the single request you hooked it on.

Comment: okok, thanks is there any hook that only occur in admin area, so that I does not register the script on my front end too, as the script is only used in admin area

Comment: use [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) hook to add js to admin-only pages. if you're doing it all in one place, you can skip registering the script and just use `wp_enqueue_script` with the same parameters. registering and enqueueing separately are helpful if your script is conditionally enqueued in different places in your code, but it's not necessary to do both if all the parameters are passed with `wp_enqueue_script`.

Comment: Thanks bro, last question.If I want to deregister script I should deregister everytime or once in the plugin deactivation hook?

Comment: deregister on every request, same as register.